# How to load record type id for lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to set the record-type-id of a `<lightning-record-edit-form>` in a Lightning Web Component. However, every time I add the code for the record type id, the page is blank. This is to create a new record, not edit one.

Controller:

```js
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import MY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/myObject__c';

export default class myClass extends LightningElement {

    @api recordTypeId;
    @api objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: MY_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    get recordTypeId() {
        console.log('get recordtypeid');
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'record type 1');
    }
}
```

Component:

```html
    <lightning-record-edit-form 
            object-api-name={myObject}
            record-type-id={recordTypeId}
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
            onsuccess={handleSuccess}
            onerror={handleError}>
```

Comment: My guess is that the form is trying to load before the wire method is being called. You should probably try to move the form inside a `<template if:true={objectInfo}>` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no tracking of your recordTypeId and no dependency linkage between getting the object info back from the server and this LWC property usage in the template. Try updating the code like:

```
@track
recordTypeId;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: MY_OBJECT })
handleObjectInfo({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        const rtis = data.recordTypeInfos;
        this.recordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'record type 1');
    }
}
```

That way when the recordTypeId changes the form markup in the template is re-processed. And the record type ID is only updated when the object info wire is actually invoked to successfully return data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy paste the code well. I updated the question to reflect what I have.

Comment: Did you try making the getObjectInfo wire a function like I have suggested? You need to have this dependency linkage before setting the record type ID.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, so I'm just going to make my own form.  Such a fundamental feature of SF should be easy to implement.  Oh well.

Comment: The lightning-record-form and lightning-record-edit-form components are a bit rough around the edges (e.g. Time fields are not handled well, you can't populate missing mandatory fields with defaults during submit, you can't pre-populate certain fields as the (record creation) form is initialized etc.). Still, writing your own from scratch is non-trivial... good luck!